# get selected checkbox values into jQuery and process to the other page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need help with the jquery. Im just starting on how to code with jQuery so im kinda newbie. please help me with some solutions,

so far i have this in the markups

```
<input type='checkbox' data-headmark=".$row['HEAD_MARK']." data-id=".$row['ID']." class='cuttingCheckbox'  name='cuttingCheckbox'/>
```

and the jquery i have so far is just disabling the checkbox once selected,

```
$('.cuttingCheckbox').change(function() {
         if (this.checked) {
           this.setAttribute("disabled", true);
         } 
       });
```

and the page who is going to use the values is the database process,

```
oci_parse($conn,"UPDATE FABRICATION_QC SET CUTTING = 'Y' 
                                   WHERE HEAD_MARK = ".$_POST["headmark"]." AND ID = ".$_POST["headmark_id"].";");
```

so the idea is sending those two values from checkbox to another page dynamically
Thanks guys for helping me

Comment: after checked call ajax function that will post to that php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question depends on if you want to send that update to the database life (I.E., right when the checkbox is checked) or on the form submit.

If live, you will use [Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to immediately post the data.  If not live, you will likey (in the jQuery) have to add something like so:

```
if (this.checked){
    this.setAttribute("disabled", true);
    var hidden=document.createElement("input");
    input.type="hidden";
    input.name=this.getAttribute("data-headmark");
    input.value=this.getAttribute("data-id");
    document.body.appendChild(input);
}
```

That way, an input of type "hidden" is added so when the form is posted, you can retrieve the variables stored in `$_POST`.  If you need to keep track of what those variables are, you could use a similar method to append to a hidden input with a fixed name.

Comment: so the basic idea is not like form type. It should update it live when user check the checkbox and after that disabling the checkbox automatically

Comment: You'll want to look at AJAX, then - jquery does it very well.  Essentially, you'll have direct control over the variables and variable names you are POST-ing, and the receiver will be a PHP page that will process those variables appropriately.  You can still use the `this.getAttribute("data-headmark")` and such to retrieve the values for those and POST them.

Comment: im stil very new to jQuery and even AJAX. Can you show me some prototype or example on how to achieve this process ?

Comment: Here you go: `$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );`
That will post the variables `name="John"` and `time="2pm"` to `test.php` - so you'd do something like `$.post("handler.php",{this.getAttribute("data-headmark"):this.getAttribute("data-id")});`
That will post a variable named `data-headmark`'s value with a value of `data-id`'s value.

Comment: and on the sql query, i use $_POST['data-headmark'] and $_POST['data-id']??

Comment: $_POST['whatever the PHP on the previous page spat out for data headmark here'] will have a value of 'whatever the PHP spat out for data-id here'.
If you want to POST them so you can retrieve them as `$_POST['data-headmark']` and `$_POST['data-id']` then try `$.post("handler.php",{data-headmark:this.getAttribute("data-headmark"),data-id:this.getAttribute("data-id")});`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50834/discussion-between-chriskonz-and-helpful)

Comment: can i moved our discussion on chat ? anyway i really appreciate your help

Comment: My computer is struggling to load chat properly.